# Why is 2700x slower than i7-6700 in redis benchmark?

Tags: performance, redis, benchmarking, cpu-architecture, amd-processor

I don't understand why is 2700x slower than i7-6700 in redis benchmark?

What else should I add?

Below are my tests.

### 1st system

- OS : CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
           Linux localhost.localdomain 5.2.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 9 13:40:33 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- CPU : AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor (pinnacle ridge 2700x)
- RAM : 16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3000 MHz (0.3 ns) * 2

```
[root@localhost ~]# redis-cli --latency
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.21 (5042 samples)
[root@localhost ~]# redis-benchmark -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -n 100000 -t set -q
SET: 110619.47 requests per second
[root@localhost ~]# redis-benchmark -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -n 100000 -t get -q
GET: 138504.16 requests per second
```

### 2nd system

- OS : CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
           Linux dmlocalhost.localdoamin 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 03:35:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- RAM : 16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)

```
[root@dmvault ~]# redis-cli --latency
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.11 (5038 samples)
[root@dmvault ~]# redis-benchmark -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -n 100000 -t set -q
SET: 248138.95 requests per second
[root@dmvault ~]# redis-benchmark -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -n 100000 -t get -q
GET: 244498.77 requests per second
```

Comment: Possibly Redis is sensitive to inter-core latency?  (https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/6ieva3/amd_ryzen_vs_x99_vs_x299_intercore_latency/) Communication between CCX clusters on Ryzen is significantly slower than between the 4 physical cores of an i7-6700 (max turbo 4GHz)

Comment: Or maybe there's a software config difference that matters, like Spectre mitigation slowing system calls more on the newer kernel?  Your Ryzen is running a kernel from 2019, but your Skylake is running a 2016 kernel from before Spectre/Meltdown were disclosed, so it probably doesn't have either mitigation backported.  Lots of simple systems calls really could slow down by that huge an amount.

Comment: Have you tried booting the Ryzen system with Spectre mitigation disabled?  (And meltdown, if it's using a naive mitigation that's always enabled, even on AMD).

Comment: I gave "noibrs noibpb nopti nospectre_v2 nospectre_v1 l1tf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable no_stf_barrier mds=off mitigations=off" as a kernel option. However, it did not affect performance very much.

Comment: I think I've read that there can still be *some* overhead for mitigations compiled in, even when you pass options to disable them.  But that is a pretty good sign that it wasn't the main problem.  Are you running the same version of Redis on both machines?  Compiled with the same compiler?  Are your numbers close to what other people report on similar hardware? (Skylake-client vs. Ryzen with 2 CCXs).  Is `redis-benchmark` expected to scale well with # of cores despite inter-core latency?

Comment: Yeah I find significant overhead even when disabling all mitigations at boot. Something like 3x slower for a do-nothing syscall than a kernel before the mitigations were introduced. The code was greatly reorganized and the mitigations are just "patched out" - you don't get the old code and optimizations back. Still, the magnitude surprised me. @Peter

Comment: This was on kernels when the mitigations were relatively new. Maybe it has improved. For real-world applications the cost of the mitigations is probably mostly in the knock-on effects in the user code, eg reloading TLB entries, branch missed, etc and my benchmark probably didn't capture that. Also, some mitigations like retpoline that are spread all over the place or depend on compiler flags, I'm not even sure if they get patched out.